# How many ways can 7 seats and 4 seats car fill with 9 people at the same time?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I applied my combination skill and came up with bunch of answers that does not correspond to the correct answer please explain first where did I miss or break my logic

If I put 3 people in 4 seats car then there will be 7 people to pick for 7 seats car

<sup>9</sup>C<sub>2</sub> * <sup>7</sup>C<sub>7</sub> = 36

If I put 3 people in 4 seat car then there will be 6 people to pick for 7 seats car

<sup>9</sup>C<sub>3</sub> * <sup>7</sup>C<sub>6</sub> = 588

If i put 4 people in 4 seats car the there will be 5 people to choose for 7 seats car

<sup>9</sup>C<sub>4</sub> * <sup>7</sup>C<sub>5</sub> = 4410

total = 5034

the correct answer is 246.

P.S:New to combinations.

Comment: Once you have chosen the people to go in the four-seater, the remaining people must go in the seven-seater; there is no further choice to make.  You shouldn't have any multiplications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that you put $3$ people in the car that seats $4$. There are, as you say, $\binom93$ ways to choose them, but once you’ve chosen them, the $6$ who are left will go in the other car: you don’t have any more choosing to do. Similarly, there are $\binom94$ ways to choose $4$ for the smaller car, but then the other $5$ automatically all go in the larger car. Thus, there are really only

$$\binom92+\binom93+\binom94=36+84+126=246$$

different possibilities.

Note that this accounts only for the distribution of the people between the two cars: if we are concerned with how they arrange themselves in each car, the number of possibilities will be *much* larger.

Comment: I misread the question - I thought that the seating within each car mattered, so I ended up getting $$11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \,\, \cdots \,\, 4 \cdot 3 \, = \, 19948400$$ Your answer makes a lot more sense, +1

Comment: If I fill the larger car first why I come up with this odd answer which is 29 ?

Comment: @Ghost: If you fill the larger car first, the answer is $$\binom97+\binom96+\binom95=36+84+126=246\,.$$ The reasoning is the same: once you decide who goes in the larger car, everyone else automatically goes in the smaller car.